# Assigning anonymous type multiple times with the same property names and types

Tags: c#, .net, linq, initialization, anonymous-types

I have some code block, and need to use the same object to be used outside the block, I can use a strong types such as:

```
Person p = null;
if(cond1)
{
    p = new Person();
    p.Name = "Name1";
    p.Age = 25;
}
else if (cond2)
{    
    p = Employees.Select(c=>new Person() {Name = c.FirstName + " " +c.LastName }).First();
    p.Age = 23;
}

if(p != null)
{
    Console.Write(p.Name);
}
```

I need to do that via anonymous types instead of person, I can't use tuples because the property names are not named, and can't create tinny classes every time I need such thing, this is a very simple case, but what about LINQ results in blocks similar to my example?

Comment: Anonymous types can only be used internally to a code block, for example, they can't be used as method parameters or return values. Writing classes don't cost a thing, if it makes sense in the business logic, create them as much as you need.

Comment: You say you "can't" create tiny classes every time you need such a thing. Why is that?

Comment: @SWeko I do need them in the same method and not in multiple methods

Comment: @PatrikHägne I mean it will be disturbing to create tens of two or three property classes to be used in a single method!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this kind of thing

```
        var person = new { Name = "" }; ;

        if (cond1)
        {
            person  = new { Name = "Bob" };
        }
        else
        {
            person  = new { Name = "John" };
        }

        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
```

Comment: This is a nice trick, thanks to this feature:  "If two or more anonymous object initializers in an assembly specify a sequence of properties that are in the same order and that have the same names and types, the compiler treats the objects as instances of the same type."

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to replace

```
Person p = null;
```

by

```
dynamic p = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating your business objects so you don't have to use anonymous types.  But a couple of quick fixes to your problem would be to use reflection or pass it as a dynamic type.

EDIT:

Oh, are you just creating new subtypes for the purpose of limiting the properties that are on type so that you don't have to specify which properties you want Console.Write() (or whatever other function) to have available to it?  I assume the data from which you're querying is available outside these functions, and if it's strongly typed then you don't need to create anonymous types but just use those types... but you'd have to specify in your Console.Write() line which properties to print, which is what I would recommend.

Comment: I need a quick way, because this type won't be used outside the block